# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForFreeDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

**build.gradle(module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""com.khaidemsandipsingha.builditbigger""
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    flavorDimensions "tier"
    productFlavors {
        paid {
            applicationId 'com.example.khaidemsandipsingha.builditbigger.paid'
            versionName '1.0-paid'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "true"
            dimension "tier"
        }
        free {
            applicationId 'com.example.khaidemsandipsingha.builditbigger.free'
            versionName '1.0-free'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PAID_VERSION", "false"
            dimension "tier"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/com.example.khaidemsandipsingha.builditbigger.paid']
        }
        paid {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/paid/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        free {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/free/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }


    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //Tests
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    //Support
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    // Added for AdMob
    freeImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

    //Add AndroidJoke
    implementation project(':androidjoke')
    //Backend
    implementation project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

**Build error output**
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForFreeDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

**gradle build -s**

- Exception is:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForFreeDebug'.
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:273)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:258)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while
>   generating the main dex list.
>           at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>           at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>           at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
>           ... 31 more Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while
>   generating the main dex list.
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:127)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
>           at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>           ... 47 more Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException:
>   com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already
>   present: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable
>           at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:114)
>           ... 50 more Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already
>   present: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable
>           at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
>           at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
>           at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
>           at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:121)
>           at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:122)
>           at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
>           at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:40)
>           at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:110)
>           at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
>           ... 51 more

GitHub project link: https://github.com/Kurosakicoder/BuildItBiggerGradle-master

Answer (score 1):

what about your application class? 
 if you don't have one, you need to create one and put the name of it in manifest 
there for your code should be like this

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name="ApplicationName"
...
>
```

and your application class will be :

```
public class ApplicationName extends MultiDexApplication{
.....

 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

> Update
>   I notice that you use

```
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
```

this is not working when you run your app in debugging try you export a release if it works then you need to add these configure in a debug build type

Comment: Hi, It is not working for me. I don't completely understand how do I implement it. Can you check my GitHub link